# Bootstrap: How to append a class and still have the BS Javascript work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry, I am new to Javascript. I am doing some simple validation on a Bootstrap Collapse. I am using a BS alert as given here:

```
   <div id ="alertMessage"  class="alert alert-danger fade in">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <strong>Info!</strong> This alert box could indicate a neutral informative change or action.
</div>
```

It works great when simply placed on the HTML page. However, I want it to fire only **IF** the JS validation script fails. The trouble is once I place it into the script it no longer fades out. I think that somehow the JS in the Bootstrap file is not being enacted. More likely, I think my script is not working correctly as the other panels do not close properly either.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("input.btn").mousedown(function () {      // THIS IS THE SUBMIT BUTTON OMN THE FORM
    var required = $("input.required").val();  // WE GRAB THE VALUES OF THE "REQUIRED FIELDS"

    if (required == "") {                   // IF ANY OF THE REQUIRED FIELDS ARE EMPTY WE EXECUTE THE FOLLOWING:


        $("#collapseOne").collapse('show');  // THIS ONE HAS ALL THE CUSTOMER DETAILS WHERE THE VALIDATION ERROR IS
        $("#collapseTwo").collapse('hide');
        $("#collapseThree").collapse('hide');
        $("#alertMessage").append("<p  class='alert alert-danger' >You have Missed Off One or More Required Fields !</p>");

    }
});
```

});

Any ideas what do so that is is fired when I want it ?

Comment: if you are validating more than one inputs with the same class, shouldn't you be using $("input.required").each() to iterate through all inputs? Anyway, once you append a class programmatically, then you have to re-bind all the funtictons, Fade, in Fade out, Click, dtc

Comment: @progrAmmar  Thanks for your thought. I'm new to JS. What does this mean: " you have to re-bind all the funtictons, Fade, in Fade out, Click, dtc" 

I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Can you provide a sample HTML form if possible?

Comment: @progrAmmar thanks for your help. I have managed to solve the problem by adding a **var alert = "false"** inside the if statement, and then checking if the var was enabled outside the if statement. if it was it tells me that there was a **required** input missing, I then run the BS alert.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

**HTML codes :**

```
   <div id="alertMessage"  class="alert alert-danger fade in">
     <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
   </div>
```

**Javascript codes**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $("input.btn").mousedown(function () {
     var required = $("input.required").val();

     if (required == "") {

       $("#collapseOne").collapse('show');
       $("#collapseTwo").collapse('hide');
       $("#collapseThree").collapse('hide');
       $("#alertMessage").append("<p>You have Missed Off One or More Required Fields !</p>");

     }
   });
```

Comment: You are not iterating to all .required as well